# Kivy: Change background color of ActionBar

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to change the color of the ActionBar from the default dark grey to a different color. I used the suggestion from @inclement from a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181250/changing-the-background-color-of-a-button-in-kivy). Here is my code:

```
ActionBar:
    background_normal: 'white_background.png'
    background_down: 'white_background.png'
    background_color: [51, 102, 255, .5]
```

The `white_background.png` is a 8px * 8px white png image.

Doing this changes the ActionBar's background color from dark grey to light grey (not the color I was expecting). I'm guessing this is due to the behavior that @inclement alluded to regarding the `background_color` having a tinting effect rather than a block color replacement.

As recommended by @AronBordin, I also tried setting the `background_normal` and `background_down` to empty strings, but this does not override the tinting behavior.

What is the correct way to replace the background color of the ActionBar?

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the background_image with a pure white image first. The correct implementation is:

```
background_image: 'white-bg.png'
background_color: .3,.3,.3,1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
    background_normal: ''
    background_down: ''
    background_color: 0, 1, 0, 1
```

And the background_color will be a rgba color. 
Take a [look here](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.context_instructions.html#kivy.graphics.context_instructions.Color). The color works as a multiplier to the texture, but if no texture is set, the vertex instruction takes the precise color of the Color instruction.

Comment: This results in the same tinting/multiplier effect that I was getting with my code. It appears that setting the `background_normal` and `background_down` to empty strings does not override this tinting behavior.

Comment: just pay attention that `background_color: [51, 102, 255, .5]` doesn't work. All RGBA values must be specified with a number between 0 and 1. 0, 1, 0, 1

Comment: `background_color: 0, 1, 0, 1` for example, is the same that 0, 255, 0 with 100% alpha

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me :

```
#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        ActionBar:
            background_image: 'assets/images/bg_normal.png'
            background_color: hex('#9C27B0')
```

The assets/images/bg_normal.png is a 10x10 white png image

Answer (score 0):

For Kivy 1.10, I think this will work just fine.

```
background_color: (0.60, 0.07, 0.70, 1)
```

use RGBA values out of 1, i.e, decimal values