# (Kivy) Calling Function From App Class - Function Object Has no Attribute

Tags: python, class, methods, kivy

This is probably the wrong way of going about this completely, so I am open to other suggestions. I am trying to change the background of a button in another class from a button press. The button .kv is here:

```
Button:
            root: 'landing_sc'
            id: filebutton
            size: 150, 150
            size_hint: None, None
            background_normal: 'folder.png'
            background_down: 'opacity.png'
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.11, 'top': .7}
            on_release: 
                root.manager.transition = FadeTransition()
                root.manager.transition.duration = 1.5
                root.IfFolder()
                root.ChangeToSlide()
                app.switch.change()
```

And here is the app class it is referring to:

```
class MySubApp(App):
    def switch(self):
        change = LandingScreen()

    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()
```

And lastly here are the methods that I am trying to use in the LandingScreen class to change the background of a button there:

```
class LandingScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LandingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.buttons = [] # add references to all buttons here
        Clock.schedule_once(self._finish_init)

def callfun(self, *args):
    self.ChangePic()

    def ChangePic(self, *args):
            self.buttons[1].background_normal = 'folder.png'
```

This seems like a massive work around that isn't working anyways. Is there a simpler way to change the attribute of a button in another class on_release? Thanks.

Comment: If the answer below is correct, please accept the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways you could achieve this. One way is to use a `property` as demonstrated below. Also, if you are wondering why you aren't getting the expected color, read [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181250/changing-the-background-color-of-a-button-in-kivy) Q and A.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<MyButton>:
    background_color: [1, 0, 0, 1] if self.active else [1, 1, 1, 1]

<RootWidget>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        size_hint: (1, .2)
        MyButton:
            text: "Screen One"
            on_release: root.sm.current = "one"
            active: root.sm.current == "one"
        MyButton:
            text: "Screen Two"
            on_release: root.sm.current = "two"
            active: root.sm.current == "two"
""")


class MyButton(Button):
    active = BooleanProperty(None)


class Manager(ScreenManager):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Manager, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        screen_one = Screen(name="one")
        screen_one.add_widget(Label(text="Screen One"))

        screen_two = Screen(name="two")
        screen_two.add_widget(Label(text="Screen Two"))

        self.add_widget(screen_one)
        self.add_widget(screen_two)


class RootWidget(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.sm = Manager()
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.add_widget(self.sm)


class TestApp(App):

    def build(App):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```