# RGBA colours not coming out as they should in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, rgba

I can't get the background colour of my kivy button to come out red, giving it rgba values of `1,0,0,1` gives me a dark maroon colour. However, if I set the colour of the text to `1,0,0,1` it does give me the correct shade of red.

I've tried various rgba combinations but to no avail. Does it have something to do with a background colour already being applied so the red mixed with a default grey makes this dark maroon colour I am seeing?

```
Button:
            text: "No"
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.2
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.5, "top": 0.4}
            background_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
            color: 1, 0, 0, 1
            on_press: root.no_btn(app.user_email)
```

Comment: as I remember as default `Button` has assigned image which color is mixed with red color and you get dark red color. You have to assign `None` in place of image and then you get correct red color. But I don't remeber name of property which keeps this image.

Comment: see this answer for [Changing the background color of a Button in Kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20181407/1832058) - you have to assing empty string to `background_normal` and `background_down` to remove images used as background in Button.