# Changing text in Kivy custom button class

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

Following code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005182/rounding-button-corners-in-kivy) I've created a simple button with rounded corners like so:

```
<RoundedButton@Button>:
background_color: 0,0,1,0  
canvas.before:
    Color:
        rgba: (.216,.118,.329,1) if self.state=='normal' else (0,.7,.7,1)  
    RoundedRectangle:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
        radius: [10,]
RelativeLayout:     
    pos: self.parent.pos
    size: self.parent.size
    Label:
        text: 'Button Text'
        font_size: 20
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y':0.5}
        id: _labeltext
```

When I use this button in my kv code, I'd like a simple way to change the text of the button, which I'd like to do using the id value '_labeltext'.
This seems like it should be simple but I've not been able to find how to change this in the KV code rather than in python (as a response to an action). I'd just like to reuse my button design multiple times with different text. For example (I know this doesn't work):

```
RoundedButton:
self.ids._labeltext.text: 'New Button Text'
```

Thanks

P.S. can't get indentation correct in the editor, apologies

Comment: The indentation in your `kv` is incorrect. Please adjust your posted `kv` to reflect the actual indentation used. Is the `RelativeLayout` part of the  `RoundedButton` ?

Comment: Yes, I had really issues with this in the text editor. I pasted the code with indentations complete but this didn't copy over. I wasn't able to then add additional tabs to correct it. Do you know how I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the text of the `RoundedButton` just as you would any other `Button`:

```
RoundedButton:
    text: 'Hello'
```

Comment: Thanks John, I tried this but it added additional text over the label I had added. I think what I'll do is change the class so there is no label, and I just modify the text property. I had used a custom label class too (with specific fonts etc. to stop me repeating code but I didn't include that detail in the questions)
Out of interest, is there a way to alter the label's text specifically? Or should it not be done that way

Comment: Still not clear what you are trying to do. The `Button` class has a `text` attribute that it displays. Your `RoundedButton` extends `Button`, so it also has its own `text` attribute that it displays. The `Label` widget that you have added is just another `Label`, unrelated to the `RoundedButton`, that is getting displayed on top of the `RoundedButton`. Try adding my answer to your `kv` and eliminating that extra `Label` to see what I mean.

Comment: You're right, I'd overlooked that I was inheriting from Button. I'm pretty new to this, the label is redundant. I'll change the class accordingly